# Unable to change button background when enable and disable

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my selected background :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@drawable/button_background" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disable_background" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

enable background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#2F98E4"
        android:startColor="#2F98E4"
        android:type="linear" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

disable background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#2F98E4"
        android:startColor="#10344E"
        android:type="linear" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

Style of button

```
 <style name="ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background_selector</item>
        <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

Button code

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_enter_pin_click"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_108"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_44"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_enter_pin_preview" />
```

above is my code when i try to enable and disable button i am unable to set background of button i don't know what i am doing mistake .

when i run this code i am getting :

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11:
> Binary XML file line #113: Error inflating class TextView
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #113: Error inflating class TextView
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.anil.gorestapp:drawable/button_background_selector with
> resource ID #0x7f0800d9
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/button_background_selector.xml from drawable resource ID
> #0x7f0800d9

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this.  Notice your two styles are identical except for the background.  Instead, make a StateListDrawable background that specifies the background for both the enabled and disabled state.  Then you can just set that as the background and merely enabling or disabling the button with setEnabled will automatically switch it for you.

Comment: can you please help me in this actually i am not able to set  background  selection  i tried with that also but did not work.

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@drawable/button_background" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disable_background" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>.  i tried like this

Comment: You have 2 falses there, one with the wrong background.  It should only have 2 items, one for enabled, one for disabled.

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@drawable/button_background" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disable_background" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>  even after kept two item then also its not working. i am getting Error inflating class TextView

Comment: i have changed  question can you please help me in this